# only open ads in browser in webview android

Tags: webview, android-webview

i want to open only Ads in browers and the rest of the all app links open internaly in webview.
please help me i want to submit this to my client. only problem with ads otherwise everything is works fine. So how can i do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements com.slotgame.slotfun.casiongo.WebView {

    WebView webView;
    LinearLayout rate, aboutus, share;

    private static final String appURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";

    String url = "https://www.youtube.com/";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toole);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // javascript enable
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.clearCache(true); // app DOES NOT save cache!
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); // save cookies
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
       // webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");


        shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, null);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest urll) {
        if (url.contains("https://www.youtube.com/")) {

            view.loadUrl(url);

            return false;
        }
        else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```